# How to read Heart Rate history from Google Fit API in Android?

Tags: java, android, google-fit

I tried to read data from Fit API history like following,

```
 private DataReadRequest queryFitnessData() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    Date now = new Date();
    cal.setTime(now);
    long endTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, -10);
    long startTime = cal.getTimeInMillis();

    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
    Log.i(TAG, "Range Start: " + dateFormat.format(startTime));
    Log.i(TAG, "Range End: " + dateFormat.format(endTime));

    DataReadRequest readRequest = new DataReadRequest.Builder()
            .aggregate(DataType.TYPE_HEART_RATE_BPM, DataType.AGGREGATE_HEART_RATE_SUMMARY)
            .bucketByTime(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
            .setTimeRange(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
            .build();

    return readRequest;
}
```

And I read the data like following,

```
DataReadRequest readRequest = queryFitnessData();

        // [START read_dataset]
        // Invoke the History API to fetch the data with the query and await the result of
        // the read request.
        DataReadResult dataReadResult =
                Fitness.HistoryApi.readData(mClient, readRequest).await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

I evaluated the output using debugger for `dataReadResult`

[image]

how can i fix this?

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: This looks good to me.  What do you think is broken?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. my fit history was empty... that was the problem. thank you

Comment: @codebot I am looking for heart bit. I have installed some app but no one store my data to google fit app. and Even I couldn't find any way to store heart data in fit app. Please share your views!

Comment: you can use the google fit app(https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.fitness&hl=en) to store your data on google fit. make sure you are using the same account.